# Using Hunspell with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, hunspell

Does anybody have any ideas of a good way to implement `Hunspell` in Silverlight? I see some 3rd party `TextBox` controls available for purchase, however I'm just looking to utilize `Hunspell` in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Design a WCF Ria Services that a list of misspelled words and their suggestions. Then it is a matter of figuring out how to highlight the mispelled words.

```
[Invoke]
public IEnumerable<WrongWord> SpellCheck(string Passage)
{
}

public class WrongWord
{
  [Key] public property int Id {get; set; }
  public string Word {get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<string> Suggestions {get; set; }
}
```

You probably can use the .NET bindings, e.g. http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/ or you can wrap hunspell yourself.

Comment: Thanks Chui. Do you mean to suggest doing the spellchecking through services only? Unfortunately my app has to support offline use so I'd need silverlight code to be able to do so. RIA implies service usage, yes?

Comment: If you need to run spell checker offline, then you need a .NET native library (which hunspell isn't), or run OOB or with elevated privilege and then use pInvoke.

Comment: Thanks again Chui. However I don't think I can pinvoke any libraries in SL4.